# The "Enter" key on soft keyboard not working for SearchView

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, searchview, enter

I'm working on a custom keyboard, but have a problem. The **Enter** key of my keyboard not working for SearchView while the **Enter** key of the default keyboard of device, works correctly. I have defined the **Enter** key in my keyboard xml file as below:

```
<Key android:codes="10"  
     android:iconPreview="@drawable/pr_sym_keyboard_return"
     android:keyWidth="12.5%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: this type of problem generated EditTextField Id. Your must to specify in your LatinKeyboard of functionality of your Enter Key Behavior.

Comment: Can you explain more about this? I check the input method type in LatinKeyboard to show appropriate icon for Enter key.